# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined when using $.each on JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My code is

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(json.responseText);
        $.each(obj.collection.response, function (i) {
          $.each(this.PRESENT_STUDENT, function (i, j) {
            $.each(j , function (i, j){
                $('#result-table tr:last').after("<tr><td>"+ j +"</td></tr>");
            })
          })
        })
```

but when i run this i get error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: Have you checked `json.responseText`? There might be no `collection.response` in your JSON.

Comment: Yes it is there if you want to have a look of my json check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029105/how-to-parse-a-json-string-when-it-has-a-number-of-objects-and-arrays-in-it/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you example works: created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6JWE7/1/):

```
$.each(obj.collection.response, function (i, val) {
    // check needed because of 'status' property (see http://jsfiddle.net/6JWE7/4/)
    if (this.PRESENT_STUDENT) {
        $.each(this.PRESENT_STUDENT, function (i, j) {
             $.each(j , function (i, j){
                 $('#result-table tr:last').after("<tr><td>"+ j +"</td></tr>");
             });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: yes i too got the result and also getting the error output. i have updated the fiddle please check it [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6JWE7/3/)

Comment: `"status": 200` is on the same 'level' as `obj.collection.response` so `this.PRESENT_STUDENT` fails because "status doesn't have `PRESENT_STUDENT`. Either remove `"status": 200` or add check (see edited answer).

Comment: Great @R. Oosterholt it worked. Now i want data to be displayed in a table such that a students detail come in one <tr></tr>. Now what i am getting is all record vertically . Actually in my html construct i have an html table with <th></th> tags for student name, roll etc. no and now i want to dynimilly add rows to it